# Импорт текста на веб-сайте в массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Как можно из файла txt, находящегося на сайте, скопировать текст в виде массива. Сам файл .txt состоит из однострочного перечисления элементов массива через запятую, например:
kdow.txt:54328433,84638573,82039587,82731236,92857236

Comment: С сайта вы получите строку. Из неё можно сделать список с помощью метода `.split()`. Например, `"54328433,84638573,82039587,82731236,92857236".split(',')` - разобьёт на список по запятой.

Answer (score 0):

С сайта вы получите строку. Из неё можно сделать список с помощью метода `.split()`.

Например, `"54328433,84638573,82039587,82731236,92857236".split(',')` - разобьёт на список по запятой.